# NLog txt file are access denied in window service

Tags: c#, nlog

I've a window service that will run every minutes and it will log some data using nlog.

What i've found out is that, during the service running sometime the log file in specify folder is access denied. When i open the log file, it shows empty and error "Access is denied".

as shown below

[image]

But my another folder is able to see all the log file, and when i click inside i can see the log data.

Here are my folder structure for log file

1) root folder  -> DataSubscriber -> "date" -> (few log file is here)

2) root folder  -> EMM -> "date" -> (few log file is here)

The first folder will always have the access is denied error, but sometime it's ok. If the error happen and i stop the service, all the log file inside the folder will gone.

Have anyone encounter this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The files are created under the context of the Windows Service user. You could do two things:

- Set the NTFS rights on the folder so for your own user so you could read/edit the files.
- Write the logs under the context of another use, use then [`ImpersonatingWrapper`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ImpersonatingWrapper-target)

Comment: It's weird, my other services using the same config is working fine. Only some of the services is having issue.